# Completing the square with multiple variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm trying to understand a solution to a PDE problem, and it involves reducing an expression by completing the square. I'm not sure how to go about the steps.

The expression is: $$-x^2+2xy-y^2+4kty$$
which becomes: $$-x^2+2(x+2kt)y-y^2$$
and finally $$-(y-2kt-x)^2+4ktx+4k^2t^2$$

Can someone show me how to arrive to this simplification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-x^2+2(x+2kt)y-y^2$$
$$=-x^2-4k^2t^2-4ktx+2(x+2kt)y-y^2+4k^2t^2+4ktx$$
$$=-(x+2kt)^2+2(x+2kt)y-y^2+4k^2t^2+4ktx$$
$$=-[(x+2kt)^2-2(x+2kt)y+y^2]+4k^2t^2+4ktx$$
$$=-[y^2-2(x+2kt)y+(x+2kt)^2]+4k^2t^2+4ktx$$
$$=-[y-(x+2kt)]^2+4k^2t^2+4ktx$$
$$=-[y-x-2kt]^2+4k^2t^2+4ktx$$
$$=-(y-2kt-x)^2+4ktx+4k^2t^2$$

Hope this is clear enough to clear your doubts.